# Meteor, Flow Router, and React: How to get FlowRouter.subsReady() function to be reactive in render

Tags: meteor, reactjs, flow-router

I am trying to create a pattern so that all the subscriptions are ready before I load the main page. Similar to Iron Router waitOn.

Take a look at this react component:

```
export const PageContainer = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="content-box">
        <div className="banner banner-primary">
          <div className="page_title pull-left">
            {this.props.pageName}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          {  FlowRouter.subsReady() ? this.props.page : (
               <div> Loading .... </div>
            )
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

as you can see I am using the `FlowRouter.subsReady()` helper to render the page or the loading text.

The problem is that this is not reactive. It just renders once but does not update and show the page once the subscription is ready.

How can I get this to be reactive?

What is the best way to use Flow Router's subscription management with React. I have a base layout and want to show loading sign before loading the page main. If I could get this function to be reactive it should work just fine.

UPDATE:

It seems like I have to attach the helper, FlowRouter.subsReady() to the get Meteor data function

```
export const PageContainer = React.createClass({
  mixins: [ ReactMeteorData ],
  getMeteorData() {
    return {
      isLoading: FlowRouter.subsReady()
    }
  },
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="content-box">
        <div className="banner banner-primary">
          <div className="page_title pull-left">
            {this.props.pageName}
          </div>
          <i className="fa fa-question-circle help-icon pull-right"></i>
        </div>
        <div>
          { this.data.isLoading  ? this.props.page : (
               <div> Loading ... </div>
            )
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

It seems to be working now. Is this the way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You accessed the problem in the wrong direction. You don't really need to check the `subsReady` of `FlowRouter` when using meteor with react. Just install the mixin `ReactMeteorData` and set the `this.data` properly, it will reactively render the `Dom`. More details [here](https://react-in-meteor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/meteor-data/)

React `render` is not reactive. The `Dom` is only re-rendered when the `props` or `state` of the component is changed

Comment: This is incorrect. You do need to check subs ready. The reason is that if the document is not ready when rendering the component, my map function will fail because it says `cannot read property members of undefined` This is because I am searching minimongo for a document to map a certain key. I cannot render the component until the subscription is done.

Comment: what you really need is checking the data of the subscription, not the `subsReady` state. Thinking about this, whether you check the `subsReady` or not, then you will still end up with pushing the data to the `state` or `props`  to let the component re-rendered again, rite ?

Comment: in my `getMeteorData` function I am returning a document by querying minimongo. Then in the render function I am using map to render list of components like so `this.data.studyDoc.members.map((user, index) => {` The issue is if studyDoc is undefined (which is will be if the subscription is not ready) then the app crashes and does not render.

Comment: @nearpoint that is my point. you can totally check on `if (this.data.studyDoc != null)  {} else {// loading}` rather than `if (isLoading)  {//loading} else {// render the data}`. In the link of the answer, there already a full example for that

Comment: I could check for null on all the data but I don't feel it is optimal. I rather just write my code trusting that my subscription has been settled. Wouldn't this be better? Anything I am missing?

Comment: Well, that is fine. In your fist post, the `subsReady` is inside the `render` function which is not correct. You can use either way (checking based on the data or checking based on the router). That is why I stated you don't **really** need to use FlowRouter. However, why need to depend on one more thing once you already have enough stuffs to work with ?